# Can I use an NFC tag to do more than just launch my app?

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I want the NFC tag data to prompt some code on my app. Is this possible and where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do lot's of stuff with NFC.

You can start by reading the [documentation of the NFC package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html) and the [guide on NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. NDEF messages (the format mostly used for Android NFC) consists of a list of records, all which can contain different types of payload. So an Android Application Record can launch your application, and (for example) an External Type Record or Mime Record can contain info which is then read by your application and acted upon.

I have created an [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) aimed at entry-level developers you might be interested in. It includes an [Android boilerplate project](http://nfc-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/files/Android%20NFC%201.2.zip).

Comment: Thanks! I understand and will explore your plugin.